Forward slash being changed to "%2F" when deploying Azure Function
I have an Azure Function that connects to an Azure File Storage account.
The File Storage Account is structure like the following:
ShareName
ShareName/folder_1
ShareName/folder_1/subfolder_1
ShareName/folder_1/subfolder_1/other_folder
ShareName/folder_1/subfolder_1/another_folder
ShareName/folder_1/subfolder_1/...
ShareName/folder_2
ShareName/folder_2/subfolder_1
ShareName/folder_3

I am able to open the ShareClient to the account, I can access all files and folders that are on ShareName/folder_1/subfolder_1 and retrieve all files and directories recursevely, with the following code:
def main():
    share_client = ShareClient.from_share_url(share_url=os.environ['STACC_URL'], credential=os.environ['STACC_KEY'])

    for file in get_files(share_client, 'folder_1/subfolder_1'):
        print(file)



def get_files(share_client: ShareClient, dir_name: os.PathLike:
    for item in share_client.list_directories_and_files(dir_name):
        if item.is_directory:
            yield from get_files(share_client, dir_name + '/' + item.name)
        else:
            yield dir_name + '/' + item.name

That works perfectly while running Azure Functions locally, and I get some output like this:
folder_1/subfolder_1/new_folder/something.pdf
folder_1/subfolder_1/other_folder/other.pdf
folder_1/subfolder_1/other_folder/new.pdf
...

However, when I deploy the code to the Azure Function, it starts failing. Oh the log, I can see that it is requesting an URL like this: https://nameofaccount.file.core.windows.net/sharename/folder_1%2Fsubfolder_1. It is of course not going to find that URL because it does not exist.
I've added a log statement for the directory that is going to be search and it does say "Getting files from directory: folder_1/subfolder_1...", but then immediately after, I get the information log referencing "Request URL: 'https://nameofaccount.file.core.windows.net/sharename/folder_1%2Fsubfolder_1?restype=REDACTED&comp=REDACTED'"
Basically, for some reason, the Azure function is transforming the "/" from the requested directory to search to the encoded "%2F". I have tried to use "\" as the standard Python escape character, but the issue remains.
How can I make the Azure Function run on Azure as it does locally and search only for the information in the specified subdirectory, recursively?

Why do you think that's a problem? This is how slashes are encoded in GET URLs.

Because the rest of the URL does have proper forward slashes and the only ones that are causing problems are the ones that I manually put into the get_files function. If I do it without slashes (i.e. just “folder_1” instead of “folder_1/subfolder_1”) it works, and gets recursively the files and directories of folder 1. Problem is, I am interested only in one folder within folder_1.

Do you need to use os.sep instead of /?

Hi @JoseVega, Did the answer worked?

The below code worked fine for me, try to change it as below:
import logging
import os
from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareClient
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    try:
        rith_url = "https://rithwik.file.core.windows.net/test"
        ri_cred = "iVdHuxigBQmrK39fZFw6bjSKORqg=="
        ri_sc = ShareClient.from_share_url(share_url=rith_url, credential=ri_cred)
        rith_dir = 'fold1/fold2'
        rf = list(rith_fl(ri_sc, rith_dir))
        rf_s = "\n".join(rf)

        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello Rithwik the Files are :\n{rf_s}")
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Hello Rithwik, ERROR : {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Hello Rithwik, ERROR as occured",
            status_code=500
        )

def rith_fl(risc: ShareClient, ri_d: str):
    for i in risc.list_directories_and_files(ri_d):
        if i.is_directory:
            yield from rith_fl(risc, f"{ri_d}/{i.name}")
        else:
            yield f"{ri_d}/{i.name}"

Output:
In local:

In Portal after Deployment:

